# Rendering an Isometric Grid in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, isometric

I'm using this to render an isometric grid at the moment:

```
for row in range(len(map_data[level])):
for tile in range(len(map_data[level][row])):
    x = (tile * tileWidth / 2) + (row * tileWidth / 2)
    y = (row * floorTileHeight / 2) - (tile * floorTileHeight / 2)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(tileImage, (x, y))
```

Which outputs this:
[Isometric Render Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMWba.png)

from this grid:

```
map_data = [[
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
]
```

However, I want to make use of the space below the original rectangle, and extend the corridor down the screen rather than across. How should I change the rendering code to render the longer corridor? ([Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVY0H.png))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first create `map_data` with more elements (your corridor) and then run it and see what's happen.

Comment: It gets to a certain x value (to the left of the window) before it starts extending off to the right and off screen.

Comment: maybe create simple, working exampla so everyone could run it and see problem, and try to make modifications.